# java.lang.IllegalStateException: while calling a method from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to get rid of this,
I am using the Google compatibility library for Fragments.  I have a the following error in log cat. Where MainMenuScreen is a FragmentActivity.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1314)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:541)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:525)
```

I am trying to call a method from a fragment which is in fragmentActivity, like the below

```
MainMenuScreen objMain= new MainMenuScreen();
                    if(SharedVariables.isTablet){

                        objMain.showFragment();}else{....}
```

And in MainMenuScreen the method is

```
public void showTrafficCasesDetails(){          
        detailsFragmentRoot.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);            
        DetailsFrag detailsFrag=new DetailsFrag ();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();       
        transaction.replace(R.id.mainScreenDetailsFrame, detailsFrag);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it...

```
MainMenuScreen objMain=(MainMenuScreen)getActivity(); if(SharedVariables.isTablet){

                        objMain.showFragment();}
```